# jQuery script for cookie in URL

Tags: jquery, string, url, cookies

I have a couple of problems with my jQuery script. myCookie variable breaks the script completely. It's supposed to be part of the url, and if I remove it I get an 'undefined' in the url caused by line 3. I have also tried adding `.attr('href', 'something')` but returns [object object].

Can anyone spot anything obvious I am missing?

```
var qstringbeast;
var myCookie = $.cookie('campaign');;
var qstringstump = $('footer div div a.button').attr('href');

var qstringamount = $('#frm-amount');
var qstringterm = $('#frm-term');

if ((qstringamount.val() || qstringterm.val()) !== undefined) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            qstringbeast = 'https://www.my-url.com/'+(myCookie)+(qstringstump)+'&product='+($('input[name=product]:checked').val())+'&amount='+(qstringamount.val())+'&term='+(qstringterm.val());
            $('a.button').attr('href',qstringbeast);
            $('a.trycta').attr('href',qstringbeast);
            $('#prodhero a.trycta').removeAttr('href');
    });
    $('input[name=product],#frm-loan-amount,#frm-term,#frm-amount-slider,#frm-term-slider').change(function() {
        qstringbeast = (qstringstump)+'&product='+($('input[name=product]:checked').val())+'&amount='+(qstringamount.val())+'&term='+(qstringterm.val());
        $('a.button').attr('href',qstringbeast);
        $('a.trycta').attr('href',qstringbeast);
        $('#prodhero a.trycta').removeAttr('href');
    });
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` all of your variables, maybe some of them are not strings

Comment: *"breaks the script completely"* . So what errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: @charlietfl Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

Comment: sounds like you didn't include the `$.cookie` plugin or are trying to use it before it is loaded or you have more than one version of jQuery.js being loaded

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 semicolon at line n°2 and some jQuery can be put inside the document.ready

Test with this code and tell me the result

```
var qstringbeast;
var myCookie = $.cookie('campaign');
var qstringstump = $('footer div div a.button').attr('href');

var qstringamount = $('#frm-amount');
var qstringterm = $('#frm-term');

if ((qstringamount.val() || qstringterm.val()) !== undefined) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            qstringbeast = 'https://www.my-url.com/'+(myCookie)+(qstringstump)+'&product='+($('input[name=product]:checked').val())+'&amount='+(qstringamount.val())+'&term='+(qstringterm.val());
            $('a.button').attr('href',qstringbeast);
            $('a.trycta').attr('href',qstringbeast);
            $('#prodhero a.trycta').removeAttr('href');

           $('input[name=product],#frm-loan-amount,#frm-term,#frm-amount-slider,#frm-term-slider').change(function() {
              qstringbeast = (qstringstump)+'&product='+($('input[name=product]:checked').val())+'&amount='+(qstringamount.val())+'&term='+(qstringterm.val());
              $('a.button').attr('href',qstringbeast);
              $('a.trycta').attr('href',qstringbeast);
              $('#prodhero a.trycta').removeAttr('href');
           });
    });

}
```

Comment: 2 semi colons won't break anything

Comment: @Zao Soula It's stating the same thing. Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function . Maybe there's a lot more going on among the entire code that is tearing it apart.

Comment: @SamualG Oh $.cookie is a Jquery plugin you need to install it before